# How to make Android Widget StackView arrange its order of display

Tags: android

I have an Android Widget which uses StackView to display lists of data. I want to be able to make the StackView show a particular list ( not necessarily how the list is arranged) first before swipping to the others.

I have two classes which made the StackView possible;
AppWidgetProvider class and StackWidgetServices class, but I don't have any idea of how to make this happen. Kindly provide me some guide.
The StackWidgetServices class act as an adapter.

```
public class StackWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new StackRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}
}

class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
private final ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
private List<Buzz> mBuzzes = new ArrayList<Buzz>();
private Context mContext;
private int mAppWidgetId;

public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
    mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}

public void onCreate() {
}

public void onDestroy() {
    mBuzzes.clear();
}

public int getCount() {
    return mBuzzes.size();
}

public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.stackwidget_item);

    if (position <= getCount()) {
        Buzz buzz = mBuzzes.get(position);

        if (buzz.picture != null) {
            try {
                Bitmap picture = imageDownloader.downloadBitmap(buzz.picture, 100, 100, 70);
                rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.stackWidgetItemPicture, picture);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Logging.e("Error reading picture file", e);
            }
        }

        if (!buzz.username.isEmpty()) {
            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.stackWidgetItemUsername, buzz.username);
        }
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.stackWidgetItemContent, Html.fromHtml(buzz.content));

        // store the buzz ID in the extras so the main activity can use it
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(HoneybuzzListActivity.EXTRA_ID, buzz.id);
        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.stackWidgetItem, fillInIntent);
    }

    return rv;
}

public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public void onDataSetChanged() {
    mBuzzes = Buzz.getBuzzes(HoneybuzzApplication.buzz, mContext);
}
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I want the StackView to display a particular stack first before others.

Comment: it depends on the adapter you use

Comment: I have edited my post by adding the adapter used

Comment: so what order do you want to have in `getViewAt`?

Comment: I plan to use an int passed as an extra from intent from MainActivity class, so, based on this integer, I want to show the StackView page. For example, if the int is 1, I want the position of 1 display first before others

Comment: so create a list of integers with values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ..., then if your `int` is 1 then remove the element from the index 1 and place it before the index 0 so the list is 1, 0, 2, 3, 4 ... i hope you know what to do with that list

Comment: You're correct but the issue is how to link this list to work with the variable 'position' at getViewAt()

Comment: `idx = list.get(position); Buzz buzz = mBuzzes.get(idx);` what issue do you mean?

Comment: I think this will produce a position, not many positions, hence, only one view will get displayed in the stack, ain't it?

Comment: I am trying your advice and will get back to you, thanks alot.

Comment: I am sorry I was arguing too much, your advice works. May God increase your wisdom. Can you write this as answer so I can mark it as the best answer? Thanks alot

Comment: write a self answer then

Comment: If I write a self answer, the credit goes to me; so I want  the credit to go to whom it should

Comment: don't worry, write a self answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my getViewAt() as advised by @pskink;

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.stackwidget_item);

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
list.add(0);
list.add(3);

if (position <= getCount()) {
// this is where the issue get solved.
    Buzz buzz = mBuzzes.get(list.get(position));

    if (buzz.picture != null) {
        try {
            Bitmap picture = imageDownloader.downloadBitmap(buzz.picture, 100, 100, 70);
            rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.stackWidgetItemPicture, picture);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Logging.e("Error reading picture file", e);
        }
    }

    if (!buzz.username.isEmpty()) {
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.stackWidgetItemUsername, buzz.username);
    }
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.stackWidgetItemContent, Html.fromHtml(buzz.content));

    // store the buzz ID in the extras so the main activity can use it
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(HoneybuzzListActivity.EXTRA_ID, buzz.id);
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.stackWidgetItem, fillInIntent);
}

return rv;
}
```